# case statement with wildcard in where clause

Tags: sql, where-in

I have a large dataset that is being returned from a view in SQL Server 2012.  I need to filter the data based on 6 different criteria.  I have set up parameters in the report and want to use the parameters in the query to reduce the size.
So I have the following situation:

```
select * from vw_ABC where p1 in @p1 and p2 in @p2 ...
```

The tricky part is how to handle a situation where the user does not want to filter on one of the criteria.  I am trying to avoid dynamic sql but if that is the only way so be it.
When the report is called the user will have all 6 parameters listed.  The default values will be 'ALL'.  They can create the report with one or all of the parameters.  Most cases it will be 2 or 3 (name city zip orderid things like this)
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you really talking bout `IN`? Or is that rather `where p1 = @p1 ...`?

Comment: where (@p1='ALL' or p1= @p1) and ... May have perfomance issues

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please tag it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are not talking about `IN` but rather about `=`. That would be:

```
select * 
from vw_ABC 
where (p1 = @p1 or @p1 = 'ALL')
  and (p2 = @p2 or @p2 = 'ALL')
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a second set of parameters to indicate whether or not the corresponding parameter needs to be used:

```
SELECT *
FROM vw_ABC
WHERE
    (@u1=0 OR p1=@p1)
AND (@u2=0 OR p2=@p2)
AND (@u3=0 OR p3=@p3)
```

This way you do not need to reserve a special value to mean *all*: if you want to use `@pX`, set `@uX` to `1`, where `X` is parameter number.

Comment: All, I will have multiple values for the parameters.  So I need to check for whether the value of p1 is "in" the list of values of @p1, not equal to the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Set up the parameters as optional and check NULLs....let me dig up an example for you

```
declare @id int = 1

select * from users u
where (@id IS NULL and u.id=u.id) or (u.id=@id)
```